# Power series of a generating function

Tags: probability, power-series, generating-functions

I'm trying to expand the following as a power series in s but I'm having trouble.

$\frac{\mu(1-s)-(\mu-\beta s)p}{\beta(1-s)-(\mu-\beta s)p}$

and I've rewritten it in the form $1/(1-x)$ where $x = \frac{(\mu - \beta)+s(\beta - \mu)}{(\mu - \mu p)+s(\beta p - \mu)}$

I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: This is $$\frac{a-bs}{c-ds}$$ with $$(a,b,c,d)=(\mu(1-p),\mu-\beta p,\beta-\mu p,\beta(1-p))$$ which, provided that $|ds|<|c|$, is $$(a-bs)\sum_{n=0}^\infty c^{-n-1}d^ns^n$$ Can you finish this?

Comment: Thank you! I've finished it now.

Comment: Then you might post what you did as an answer.

Comment: Actually I made  mistake. I'm confused because if you expand the bracket into the sum, you are left with an $s^n$ term and an $s^(n+1)$ term, but I only want an $s^n$ term

Comment: Yes -- which is why you should show what you did.

Comment: $(a−bs)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c^{-n-1}d^{n}s^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (ac^{-n-1}d^{n}s^{n} + bc^{-n-1}d^{n}s^{n+1}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} s^{n}(ac^{-n-1}d^{n}+sbc^{-n-1}d^{n}) $

Comment: Right, but note that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty bc^{-n-1}d^ns^{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty bc^{-n}d^{n-1}s^n$$ and rejoice...